# FM radio Transmitter - frequency drifting

Tags: rf, radio

First can someone explain to me how this FM transmitter circuit work?
[image]

Second, after replacing Q2 with a blt81, I got a Frequency drifting problem. Once it's running for a while, I need to re-tune my radio. The transistor is not hot none warm to touch, and the power supply is 6v regulated, and it's tuned into around 88mhz.

Comment: Your oscillator is running open-loop, so it will naturally drift over time. Modern designs typically use a phase locked loop frequency synthesizer to avoid this.

Comment: This circuit is one step above the single-transistor oscillator in the foodchain of simple FM transmitters. next step: llok for one that uses a crystal + varactor dioded in the oscillator (and, as your current circuit, a buffer stage after the oscillator).

Comment: I see weaknesses in that design, where did it come from. I ask because I don't see any benefit in trying to explain how something works when the designer appears to be an amateur.

Comment: Actually this circuit works very fine. I have been listening musics from it for hours. It only became problematic when I change Q2. I changed Q2 because I want to improve the range of this radio, then make a pcb out of it. The circuit really works very good. This kit came from China, so I guess someone is China designed it.

Comment: Is Q2 running warmer than the original and heating the oscillator? That would definitely cause drift.